# jquery-jtable: exporting selected lines using ajax/jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, jquery-jtable

I need to implement an export to Excel function, but only for selected lines of the jtable, in a JSP environment.

My question is: what is the best way to do it? From the jtable, I pick the $('#SearchResultTable').jtable('selectedRows') and post it (using jquery $.post() ) to my servlet (that is generating the Excel file using poi). Everything good until I have to pick up the response from the servlet. Turns out I cannot save it to disk or prompt the browser to download it, since ajax is basically javascript, and thus have no access to the disk.

Is there a better way to do this? I want to be able to name and save the resulting file.

This is my call function which handles the post:

```
toolbar: {
    items: [{
        icon: 'art/excel_ico.gif',
        text: 'Esporta in Excel',
        display: 'download="Report.xls"',
        click: function() {
            return $.post("ExcelExport", {n: "Magazzino", t: $('#SelectedRowList')[0].innerHTML})
            .done(function(data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            });
        }
    }]
},
```

Thank you for your help,
Fabio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I used a form instead of the "toolbar:" item in JTable. To whoever may be interested:

I removed the "toolbar" item from JTable init function.
Added a form to the page, like this:

```
<div id="formWrapper">
    <form id="exportForm" action="ExcelExport" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="exportRows" id="exportRows">
        <input type="hidden" value="Ordini" name="dataType" id="dataType">
        <input type="submit" value="Esporta">
    </form>
</div>
```

Styled the form using css to make it look like the button on the JTable toolbar.

In the JTable init, I added a selectionChange item, like this:

```
selectionChanged: function() {
  var $selectedRows = $('#SearchResultTable').jtable('selectedRows');
  $('input:hidden[name="exportRows"]').val("");

  $selectedRows.each(function() {
    var record = $(this).data('record');

    $('input:hidden[name="exportRows"]').val($('input:hidden[name="exportRows"]').val()
        + record.id. ... );
  });
}
```

So every time I change something on the JTable selection, the value of exportRows changes.
The form points to my servlet that can then send back the data as an Excel file, which I can name and save.

Hope it helps.
Fabio.